# Custom save method on model - combine fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'd like to make a custom save method on a model that combines values from two of it's other fields, one of which is a value stored in a foreign key relation.

For instance, given this model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text = charfield()
    date = datefield()
    user = ForeignKey(other model)
    key = integerfield()
    unique = charfield()
```

I'd like to be able to save the field titled unique as a combination of both the user username  from the foreign key, and the key field, which is an auto-incrementing integer field. Is something like this possible? I searched for similar questions but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is of course that you won't have a key until you've saved the model at least once. So your save method will need to call the superclass save, get the key, set the unique field, then save again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django post_save signal to modify the data after the first save

Should be something like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
   obj = kwargs['instance']
   obj.unique = obj.user + str(obj.key)
   obj.save()
```

Doc on signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/